# How do I add rules for Codeigniter pages to be viewable under two seperate domain?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cross-domain

I am working on a project right now which requires a user to register and Sign up on some different domain and view its pages on other domain. to make you understand the scenario

The user will login,register and access his profile on domain1.com while will veiw other pages on domain2.com which will be accessible once logged in through domain1.com. I had build this whole project under same codeigniter project and need to know if I can keep the folder as it is and add rules per page so that some pages are only viewable through domain1.com and other only through domain2.com ?

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same thing some time back, not sure if this is good approach -

1. modify index.php to include some globals like - SITENAME based on   $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].
2. Have a BaseController and let all other controllers extend from this one.
3. In BaseController -> index() do the required validation, may be set some globals for models and views.
4. It is better to separate the views, for this use a wrapper or a common view generator file which will get the view files from specific views    folders.
5. Use the globals specified in
   BaseController to fetch domain    specific data from Database.

However, the way to go would be to have different setup for all the different domains. That way you have a lot of flexibility in modifying the code later on. Otherwise with the approach discussed above - you might end up with a lot of if-else conditions.